# Kendo UI Grid - Parsing query params into DataSourceRequest without using MVC

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create `DataSourceRequest` without actually running on ASP.NET MVC.

If I were on MVC, I could use:

```
public ActionResult GetResults([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
...
```

But, I cannot use MVC (reasons, you know...) so what I am looking for is something like `AmazingParsingKendoLibrary.ParseFromQueryString()` which will return `DataSourceRequest`

Is there any support for programmatic parsing like this?

Comment: Look into datasource [parametermaps](http://blog.codebeastie.com/kendo-grid-passing-datasourcerequest-from-your-own-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene, but there is still used the controller binding not manual parsing query string into DataSourceRequest.

Answer (score 0):

This method works as I use it to replicate the grid when doing a custom file export:

```
setRequestObject: function () {
    var grid = $("#YOUR_GRID_ID").data("kendoGrid");
    this.requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
        .options.parameterMap({
            page: grid.dataSource.page(),
            sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
            filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
        });

    var pageArg = "page=" + (this.requestObject.page || '~');
    var sortArg = "sort=" + (this.requestObject.sort || '~');
    var psizeArg = "pageSize=" + grid.dataSource._pageSize;
    var filterArg = "filter=" + (this.requestObject.filter || '~');
    this.exportFileUrl = pageArg + "&" + sortArg + "&" + psizeArg + "&" + filterArg;
},
```

I hope this helps. Good luck